# Drawing a canvas line based on variables

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, johnny-five

I'm working with Arduino and I'm using an Accelerometer. I want to make a 2D line based on the `x` and `y` variables from the accelerometer.

I'm trying to it with this code:

```
board.on("ready", () => {
  const accelerometer = new Accelerometer({
    controller: "MPU6050"
  });
  accelerometer.on("change", function () {
    const {
      acceleration,
      inclination,
      orientation,
      pitch,
      roll,
      x,
      y,
      z
    } = accelerometer;
      const $yPos = y * 100 * 10;
      const $canvas = document.querySelector(`.simulation__line`);
        if ($canvas.childElementCount > 0) {
          $canvas.innerHTML = ``;
        }
      const drawing = $canvas.getContext("2d");
      drawing.beginPath();
      drawing.moveTo(1000, 1000 - $yPos);
      drawing.lineTo(0,  1000);
      drawing.lineTo(-1000, 1000 + $yPos);
      drawing.stroke();
      drawing.clearRect(1000, $yTest, drawing.width, drawing.height);  
  });
});
```

So every time the accelerometer changes variables, it draws a new line. This results in a lot of lines, but I want only one which is constantly changing. I tried to do it with the if statement `if ($canvas.childElementCount > 0)`, but this won't help.

Comment: Use `drawing.clearRect(0, 0, drawing.width, drawing.height);` to clear the canvas at the top of your function before drawing a new line

Comment: When I do this, it still keeps drawing lines

Comment: Why are you clearing the innerHTML of the canvas? Elements inside a html canvas are only displayed if the browser does not support the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of drawing something on a canvas with a variable.
I believe your issue is in the way you are using the `clearRect` to clear the canvas

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="99" value="10" id="slider" oninput="draw()">
<br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script>
  function draw() {
    y = document.getElementById("slider").value
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(0, y, 250, 3);
  }

  // init canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.height = (canvas.width = 250)/2;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  draw();
</script>
```

Run that code snippet to see it in action.
The slider controls the Y position of a "line" that I'm drawing in the canvas, there should be just one line visible on the screen at any time.

The key is to wipe the screen:
`ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`
before we draw anything

---

Looking at your code you are doing a few things inside the "accelerometer change" function that you should consider doing outside here is what I mean:

```
  const $canvas = document.querySelector(`.simulation__line`);
  const drawing = $canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Those should not be changing as the accelerometer changes so I would keep them out

---

The other sticky point is your call to:

```
  drawing.clearRect(1000, $yTest, drawing.width, drawing.height);
```

- that should be the first before you start drawing anything
- not sure why to start at `1000, $yTest` you should clear the entire canvas start at `0,0`
- and the `drawing.width, drawing.height` are not the same as `canvas.width, canvas.height` if I change that on my example it certainly will not wipe the canvas